# How to get only the first value from an optional property?

Tags: sparql

Like in the SQL aggregate MAX, MIN or FIRST, it gets only one value, not duplicating lines.

### Real Wikidata case

Where the OPTIONAL clause expands from 253 to 257 lines:

```
# Countries and its codes
SELECT ?code  ?item ?itemLabel ?osmId
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P297 ?code.
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P402 ?osmId .}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ?code
```

[try here](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20Countries%20and%20its%20codes%0ASELECT%20%3Fcode%20%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FosmId%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP297%20%3Fcode.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP402%20%3FosmId%20.%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fcode)

**I need only one (any) `osmId`**. 
How to do something like `FIRST{OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P402 ?osmId .}}` ?

---

NOTES:

- it is not a duplicate of [How to get only the most recent value from a Wikidata property?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49066390/287948)
- it is not a duplicate of [Why does this Wikidata SPARQL query only work for the first element in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62488249/287948)
- ... no exactly need for **simple** "any first".

Answer (score 3):

Here a WIKI answer (please **you can edit** to enhance this answer!)

```
# Countries and its codes
SELECT ?code  ?item ?itemLabel
       (MAX(?osmId) as ?osmId_max) (COUNT(?code) as ?osmId_n)  
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P297 ?code.
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P402 ?osmId .}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
GROUP BY ?code  ?item ?itemLabel 
ORDER BY ?code
```

[try](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20Countries%20and%20its%20codes%0ASELECT%20%3Fcode%20%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28MAX%28%3FosmId%29%20as%20%3FosmId_max%29%20%28COUNT%28%3Fcode%29%20as%20%3FosmId_n%29%20%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP297%20%3Fcode.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP402%20%3FosmId%20.%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fcode%20%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fcode)

The `COUNT(?code)` is only to check the lines where `osmId` was not an Unique-ID.

Other simple solution to filter only the first option?

---

#### Using SAMPLE

As the @ValerioCocchi suggestion, we can use [SAMPLE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#defn_aggSample) instead MAX:

```
SELECT ?code  ?item ?itemLabel (SAMPLE(?osmId) as ?osmId_sample)
WHERE
{
  ?item wdt:P297 ?code.
  OPTIONAL{?item wdt:P402 ?osmId .}
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
GROUP BY ?code  ?item ?itemLabel 
ORDER BY ?code
```

[try](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23%20Countries%20and%20its%20codes%0ASELECT%20%3Fcode%20%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%28SAMPLE%28%3FosmId%29%20as%20%3FosmId_sample%29%20%0AWHERE%20%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP297%20%3Fcode.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP402%20%3FosmId%20.%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fcode%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fcode)

*SAMPLE* use a little bit less CPU-time, but the main motivation to use is when you don’t care which value is returned. In the case of Wikidata, when the property-value is to be unique but there are some (minimal) errors, and you can ignore them.

NOTE about the `osmId`: the advantage of *MAX* in this particular query, using an numeric ID related to a temporal sequence, is that it can be a "fresher" ID... But in OpenStreetMap (OSM) the strategy can be the inverse: most old is the most stable ID. So, *SAMPLE* make sense also in a context of ignorance about better strategy.

#### Using FILTER

The @StanislavKralin suggestion:

```
SELECT ?code  ?item ?itemLabel ?osmId
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P297 ?code.
  OPTIONAL{
    ?item wdt:P402 ?osmId 
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {
      ?item wdt:P402 ?osmId, ?osmId_ .
      FILTER (?osmId_ > ?osmId)
    }
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY ?code
```

[try](http://w.wiki/34Lb)

Seems more verbose.

Comment: You can also look at using the `SAMPLE` function in SPARQL.